# Fetch data from sql database using Pyodbc package

Tags: python, sql-server, wildcard, pyodbc, streamlit

I have a streamlit app that retrieve data from sql server database where i am using pyodbc.

I have an select  query where i try to select data based on user input using wild card inside the sql query.

The problem is that when the user **search on any field beside the ID** it does not return anything.

## Database :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t1](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [first] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [last] [nchar](50) NULL,
    [Rating] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_t1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

## Python code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import streamlit as st

advanced_search_term_list = []

if len(advanced_search_term_list)>0:

   sql="select * from testDB.dbo.t1 where (ID = ? OR ID is null) and (first LIKE  ? OR first is null) and (last LIKE ? or last is null) and (Rating = ? or Rating is null) "   

   param0=advanced_search_term_list[0]

   param1=f'%{advanced_search_term_list[1]}%'

   param2=f'%{advanced_search_term_list[2]}%'

   param3=advanced_search_term_list[3]

   rows = cursor.execute(sql,param0,param1,param2,param3).fetchall()
```

The query just return data of the **param0**

Where is the error in my code ?

Comment: `ID = ? OR ID is null` is going to fail if you pass `null` as the first parameter. Ideally you should use named parameters, then you would have `ID = @id OR @id IS NULL OR ID IS NULL` but Pyodbc doesn't support them. Maybe try `ID = ISNULL(?, ID) OR ID is null`

Comment: i tried your comment but still did not work

Comment: You may try with `(first LIKE  CONCAT('%', ?, '&') OR first is null)` and `param1=advanced_search_term_list[1]`.

Comment: i tried your comment but it display the below error:
`ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ')'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to fix these issues:

- Use a parameter, not the column name in the `IS NULL` part of the `WHERE` condition (as @Charlieface explained in the comments)
- Use `LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')` to handle correctly then Python's `None` values when you use `cursor.execute()`.

The following working example is a solution to your problem:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t1] (
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [first] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [last] [nchar](50) NULL,
    [Rating] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
INSERT INTO [dbo].[t1] ([first], [last], [Rating])
VALUES 
    ('AB', 'CD', 100),
    ('EF', 'GH', 101),
    ('IJ', 'KL', 100)
```

Python:

```
sql = (
    r"select ID, first, last, Rating "
    r"from dbo.t1 "
    r"where "
        r"(ID = ? OR ? IS NULL) AND "
        r"(first LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') OR ? IS NULL) AND "
        r"(last LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') OR ? IS NULL) AND "
        r"(Rating = ? OR ? IS NULL)"   
)
# Only for test. The values of the advanced_search_term_list
# come from the user input.     
advanced_search_term_list = [1, 'AB', None, 100]
param0 = advanced_search_term_list[0]
param1 = advanced_search_term_list[1]
param2 = advanced_search_term_list[2]
param3 = advanced_search_term_list[3]

for row in cursor.execute(sql, [param0, param0, param1, param1, param2, param2, param3, param3]) :
    print(row.ID)
    print(row.first)
    print(row.last)
    print(row.Rating)
    print("<br>")
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply i tried your answer it just return the **ID** field and  not all the  columns for this record.... when i debug the code the row variable includes just **None** where the expected result was :   `None, 'AB', None, 100`

Comment: @khaledM_dev, include the needed columns in the `SELECT` statement and fetch them properly. See the updated answer.

Comment: this was my mistake ... but still if i let the ID filed empty and try to select record based on any field beside the `ID`  **IT STILL RETURN NOTHING**

Comment: I tried something else .... I exclude the ID field from the user input and from the sql statement and it works as expected and return the correct records ... But i need to allow the user to search using  ID field